# Getting HTTP protocol version from response headers in Vue.js with vue-resource

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I’m trying to get and print the HTTP protocol version of the target in requests made by `vue-resource` in a Vue.js component. I don’t have any problem in getting headers like `Data` or `Server`: being on `localhost` I use a proxy to bypass the CORS limitations as well, but I can’t figure out how to do the same with that. As far as I know, both Chrome and Firefox developer tools refer to the HTTP protocol version in the request (not in the response), so using `response.headers.get("foo");` as [explained in the official documentation](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md) doesn’t work, and I don’t have a `request` variable set. I just need to show if the target uses HTTP 1.x or 2.x in a string like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` — I can’t understand if `Vue.http.interceptors` could help and how. I guess it shouldn’t be that hard… thanks in advance!

EDIT: Unrelated to Vue.js itself, but [`resource.nextHopProtocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/nextHopProtocol) did the trick — on Firefox, at least. Being a Candidate Recommendation, it doesn’t work with all the browsers.